# Grape API - problem making a post request using curl with data option

Tags: ruby, ruby-grape

I have an endpoint written in Grape that inherits from the base class which looks like this:

```
module API
  class Core < Grape::API
    default_format :json
    prefix :api
    content_type :json, 'application/json'

    mount ::Trips::Base
  end
end
```

This is my endpoint:

```
module Trips
  class TripsAPI < API::Core
    helpers do
      params :trips_params do
        requires :start_address, type: String
        requires :destination_address, type: String
        requires :price, type: Float
        requires :date, type: Date
      end
    end

    resources :trips do
      params do
        use :trips_params
      end
      desc 'Creates new ride'
      post do
        Rides::CreateRide.new(params).call
      end
    end
  end
end
```

When I make an explicit post request it works fine.

```
curl -d "start_address=some address&destination_address=some address&price=120&date=10.10.2018" -X POST http://localhost:3000/api/trips
```

When I try to make a post request using `curl` with -d option I get an error: `{"error":"start_address is missing, destination_address is missing, price is missing, date is missing"}`

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/vnd.api+json" -X POST -d '{ "start_address": "asdasd", "destination_address": "asdasdada", "price": 120, "date": "10.10.2018" }' http://localhost:3000/api/trips
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out. `-d` sends the Content-Type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` which means I needed to specify `JSON` Content-Type in the Header which I didn't do. What I did to solve it was:

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{ "start_address": "asdasd", "destination_address": "asdasdada", "price": 120, "date": "10.10.2018" }' http://localhost:3000/api/trips
```